# is "backgroundWorker" suitable for my code in c#

Tags: c#

I want to copy some directy to somewhere with .bat file. My bt file is this.

```
@ECHO OFF

set SETUP_FILE_DIR=%cd%
echo Please wait ...

:NORM
@ECHO OFF
xcopy "%SETUP_FILE_DIR%\%2" "%1" /S /E /H /q /c
echo Files are copied!

pause
```

and i want to use progress bar for all directory copy operation. For example:

```
if one file is copied, progress bar is increased.
...
```

I used in c# Process but not work. when WindowStyle is hidden, window is visible. I dont understand how to occur this. Now I want to try backgroundWorker.

Is it appropriate for this project do you think?

and

what is the difference between Process and backgroundWorker?

Comment: Why are you using batch files for copy or is this just an example bat file ?

Answer (score 0):

Process starts an external process, optionally waiting for a return. BackgroundWorker runs a task in a background thread and includes events to run at different stages. I'd go with BackgroudWorker.